# mongodb 'failed to connect to server' error despite same connection working previously

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

**UPDATE:**
Running the `getSections` function by itself with manually provided parameters seems to work fine. Upon printing out the parameters that cause the error, it's a different set every time...

I have an updateCurrentTerm() function that calls a few different functions inside it, all of which update different collections of the same database. Each of these make the connection to the db in the exact same way, as such:

```
MongoClient.connect(MONGOURL + term, (err, db) => {
```

Where `MONGOURL` is `'mongodb://localhost:27017/'` and `term` is `'4650'`. However, the connection seems to work for `getSchools`, `getSubjects`, `getCourses`, but NOT `getSections`. Here is the full error I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null
    at /Users/Joon/sans/app.js:129:26
    at connectCallback (/Users/Joon/sans/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:315:5)
    at /Users/Joon/sans/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:222:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

I investigated further: the db parameter of the MongoClient.connect callback being null meant that the err parameter was not null. The err parameter contained this:

```
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at .<anonymous> (/Users/Joon/sans/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at emit (events.js:188:7)
    at .<anonymous> (/Users/Joon/sans/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:271:12)
    at g (events.js:286:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Joon/sans/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:165:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:286:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect' }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

**app.js**

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import request from 'request-json';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

const API = request.createClient('http://www.northwestern.edu/class-descriptions/');
const MONGOURL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const EVENT = new EventEmitter();


const makeRequest = (query, type, callback) => {
    // Possible types:
    // terms
    // schools
    // subjects
    // courses
    // sections
    // details

    // Prepare query with correct ending
    if (type === 'terms') {
        query = 'index-v2.json';
    } else if (type === 'details') {
        query += '-v2.json';
    } else {
        query += '/index-v2.json';
    }

    API.get(query, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);

            callback(null, err);
        } else {
            // Parse out last non-data term
            const last = body[body.length - 1];
            const lastKeys = Object.keys(last);
            if (lastKeys.length === 1 && lastKeys[0] === 'ignore') {
                body.pop();
            }

            callback(body, null);
        }
    });
}

const getTerms = (callback) => {
    // TODO: Refactor to insert only if new term
    MongoClient.connect(MONGOURL + 'terms', (err, db) => {
        const coll = db.collection('data');
        coll.remove(); // Start clean
        makeRequest('', 'terms', (data, err) => {
            if (!err) {
                coll.insertMany(data, (err, result) => {
                    db.close();
                    callback(data);
                });
            } else {
                db.close();
            }
        });
    });
};

const getSchools = (term, callback) => {
    // term is the term id (not the mongodb _id)
    MongoClient.connect(MONGOURL + term, (err, db) => {
        const schools = db.collection('schools');
        makeRequest(term, 'schools', (data, err) => {
            if (!err) {
                schools.insertMany(data, (err, result) => {
                    db.close();
                    callback(data);
                });
            } else {
                db.close();
            }
        });
    });
};

const getSubjects = (term, school, callback) => {
    // term is the term id (not the mongodb _id)
    // school is the school id (not the mongodb _id)
    MongoClient.connect(MONGOURL + term, (err, db) => {
        const subjects = db.collection('subjects');

        const query = term + '/' + school;
        makeRequest(query, 'subjects', (data, err) => {
            if (!err) {
                subjects.insertMany(data, (err, result) => {
                    db.close();
                    callback(data);
                });
            } else {
                db.close();
            }
        });
    });
};

const getCourses = (term, school, subject, callback) => {
    // term is the term id (not the mongodb _id)
    // school is the school id (not the mongodb _id)
    // subject is the subject abbv
    MongoClient.connect(MONGOURL + term, (err, db) => {
        const courses = db.collection('courses');

        const query = term + '/' + school + '/' + subject;
        makeRequest(query, 'courses', (data, err) => {
            if (!err) {
                courses.insertMany(data, (err, result) => {
                    db.close();
                    callback(data);
                });
            } else {
                db.close();
            }
        });
    });
};

const getSections = (term, school, subject, course, callback) => {
    // term is the term id (not the mongodb _id)
    // school is the school id (not the mongodb _id)
    // subject is the subject abbv
    // course is the course abbv
    MongoClient.connect(MONGOURL + term, (err, db) => {
        console.log(err);
        const sections = db.collection('sections');

        const query = term + '/' + school + '/' + subject + '/' + course;
        makeRequest(query, 'sections', (data, err) => {
            if (!err) {
                sections.insertMany(data, (err, result) => {
                    db.close();
                    callback(data);
                });
            } else {
                db.close();
            }
        });
    });
};

const getDetails = (term, school, subject, course, section, callback) => {
    // term is the term id (not the mongodb _id)
    // school is the school id (not the mongodb _id)
    // subject is the subject abbv
    // course is the course abbv
    // section is the section id (not the mongodb _id)
    MongoClient.connect(MONGOURL + term, (err, db) => {
        const details = db.collection('details');

        const query = term + '/' + school + '/' + subject + '/' + course + '/' + section;
        makeRequest(query, 'details', (data, err) => {
            if (!err) {
                details.insertMany(data, (err, result) => {
                    callback(data);
                });
            } else {
                db.close();
            }
        });
    });
};

const updateCurrentTerm = () => {
    MongoClient.connect(MONGOURL + 'terms', (err, db) => {
        const terms = db.collection('data');
        // Find term with max id (not mongodb _id)
        terms.find().sort({id:-1}).limit(1).next((err, doc) => {
            EVENT.emit('maxTerm', doc.id);
            db.close();
        });
    });

    EVENT.on('maxTerm', (term) => {
        MongoClient.connect(MONGOURL + term, (err, db) => {
            db.collection('schools').remove();
            db.collection('subjects').remove();
            db.collection('courses').remove();
            db.collection('sections').remove();
            db.collection('details').remove();
            db.close();
            EVENT.emit('clean', term);
        });
    });

    EVENT.on('clean', (term) => {
        getSchools(term, (data) => {
            EVENT.emit('updatedSchools', term, data);
        });
    });

    EVENT.on('updatedSchools', (term, data) => {
        data.forEach((school) => {
            getSubjects(term, school.id, (newData) => {
                EVENT.emit('updatedSubjects', term, school.id, newData);
            });
        });
    });

    EVENT.on('updatedSubjects', (term, school, data) => {
        data.forEach((subject) => {
            getCourses(term, school, subject.abbv, (newData) => {
                EVENT.emit('updatedCourses', term, school, subject.abbv, newData);
            });
        });
    });

    EVENT.on('updatedCourses', (term, school, subject, data) => {
        data.forEach((course) => {
            getSections(term, school, subject, course.abbv, (newData) => {
                EVENT.emit('updatedSections', term, school, subject, course.abbv, newData);
            });
        });
    });
}

updateCurrentTerm();
```

Comment: could you share your mongod log too?

Comment: Here's a log of starting mongod then running app.js once: https://gist.github.com/Joonpark13/e815c260820db9343f3c7f0909d39c2c

Comment: Have you checked out `term` of `getSchools`, `getSubjects`, `getCourses`, `getSections` when `updateCurrentTerm()`? It should be the same, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you're running a query, you're creating a new instance and it's too many connection to your mongod! That won't work since each instance will create and hold at least one connection (but by default, 10) and those connections will only be removed if the Java GC cleans up your Mongo instance or when you invoke close().

Creating a new connection to Mongo is very costly and it would decrease your mongod performance too. so create a single Mongo instance and keep it alive as long as possible! Implementing a MongoFactory with a static method getInstance() that returns a lazily created instance will do the trick just fine.

Comment: I ended up refactoring my code to have much, much fewer connections in total, and it seems to work with very few errors now. Thank you!